# I want to remove the header of each lines from the file using shell script or python

Tags: command-line, scripts, python

I am new to shell script I am having difficulty in figuring out
I want to remove the header of each lines from the file and concatenate the rest of the text in a different file and someone please help me with the same. Here is how my file looks like:

```
chr22|23521891|23632600
ACCCGTGTGGCAGCCACCCACAGCAGATCCACAACGTGAGAGGCCCGCTGAAACAAGGGTGCTG
chr9|133729451|133763062
AGCCCTTCAGCGGCCAGTAGCATCTGACTTTGAGCCTCAGGGTCTGAGTGAAGCCGCTCGT
```

I want to remove the lines `chr22|23521891|23632600` `chr9|133729451|133763062` and concatenate the rest in a different file.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `grep -v '|'` to filter out the lines that don't have the `|` symbol, which would leave only the FASTA sequences. That can be combined with `> new.txt` to write a new file.

Comment: No it is not working its not printing anything I think it is more like a identifier of that line chr22|23521891|23632600 ATGCTGCAAA

Comment: @AnkitaSrivastava Interesting. Was this file generated on windows ?  Check with `cat -v input.txt`  and see if your input file has `^M` at the end of each line.

Comment: No the files were not generated on windows ..just now I checked with awk so they are actually column1  of the file , it more like column1 the identifier and column 2 id the sequences ATGC.... so now I am able extract column 2 in a separate file but I am not able club both the sequence and the command I am using now is                       awk '{print $2}' try1.bed >try2.bed   so I need to join as single string could you please help me with the same

Comment: @AnkitaSrivastava If you mean joining all `$2` from the file as single line, the  `awk '{ printf "%s",$2 }END { print}' try1.bed` should do it.

Comment: yeah it is working fine now I have used two steps of the commands first to generate file containing only column 2 i.e.    awk '{print $2}' try1.bed >try2.bed       and then I have used the command suggested by in try2.bed i.e.          awk '{ printf "%s",$1 }END { print}' try2.bed>try3.bed .                                                                        Thank you so much for help! :)